# What is the best form approach for a single question with 9 options?

Tags: forms, radio-buttons, surveys, onboarding

We are in the process of creating a survey style onboarding flow and was curious if it is ok to break the rules here? I understand that once the number of choices gets over 6 or 7, it is best to use a dropdown menu, however, for this instance it is the only question on screen and seems like exposing all the options would be quicker and easier to complete.

The second part of this question would be the layout of the options (on desktop). Which layout would to recommend for quickest scan-ability?

1. Left to right list - Similar to a tag group style selection and uses less viewport height. Also feels less organized.
2. Three column, Top to bottom
3. Three column, Phone style layout

[image: Layouts]

Comment: **A.** Guidelines are not laws. Do what you think works best for your specific situation. **B.** Option 2.

Comment: If the expected input is a number, let them write a number in an input field of type `number`. Also, "How old are your students?" is a better grammar form.

Comment: Thanks @musefan. What makes you lean towards option 2?

Comment: Thanks @Adriano. Allowing them to write in any number seems like more work for the user and would potentially allow them to enter strange things that would not map to our logic/current limitations. Appreciate the grammar suggestion, I actually changed that yesterday after posting.

Comment: @Rohrski: My mistake... I actually meant option 3! The alignment is better than option 1, and the readability is better than option 2. People read from left-to-right (at least the English language anyway)

Comment: By the way, you CAN restrict the min and max values for an input field: https://stackoverflow.com/a/37215472

Comment: @Adriano Thanks. It still seems like an additional burden is put on the user to understand/read the rules of the free-form input. e.g. the range can only include 2 directly subsequent ages between 5 and 14, no multiples or larger ranges, etc.

Comment: Go for option 3

Answer (score 0):

HTML5 allows for a number input, which has a + or - spinner and as someone mentioned you can set a min/max value. This will do your server side validation (prevent anything but whole numbers from 5-14 as you wanted. Your devs will need to do serverside validation (samething with the radio buttons they have to be serverside validated as well).

Typing in a number is pretty easy and takes less space than all those radio buttons. The radio buttons are honestly the wrong thing to use in my opinion, where there is a simpler solution.

Comment: As I understand the question the answers are labels ("5-6") and not numbers. So I don't think a number spinner would work here.